# How to Enable FILESTREAM feature in sql server 2008 developer edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem in activating the filestream feature in sql server 2008 
I have done the following steps but could not succeeded..

1) ran the sql server management studio as an administrator, right click the server instance and Facets, dialog is opened from dropdown select sever configuration and from list select FileStreamAccessLevel and set to FullAcess and  then restart the instance. Then I run the query and i again get the error FILESTREAM feature is disabled. Then I again perform the previous steps to saw whether Filestream is enabled or not, I saw that it is still disabled.
Image Link:
http://sdrv.ms/LkHZsn

2) I also open the MSSQLSERVER properties, and I found that the FileStream Tab is not present, I don't know why ? I have installed all the featuers of sql server 2008 developer edition including full text search, analysis services, integration serv etc.
Image Link
http://sdrv.ms/R5Ojm3

3) I also ran the spconfigure command but still not suceeded. I open the server instance properties, select Advanced from the left pane, and on File Stream Access level I select Full acess enabled, below a radio button is present with name configured values, currently it is select, but when I select running values, it displays FileStream is disabled. 
images Link:
http://sdrv.ms/MUpEiK
http://sdrv.ms/LWx8ow

4) I also open sql sever config manager, select sql services but nothing appears, see the below image.
http://sdrv.ms/R5PxOa
Please help me in solving this problem

Thanks

Comment: Is the SQL Server Browser service running? How about the RPC service? Have you installed the latest service pack? Have you walked through http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx?

Comment: all the services are enabled and running.

Comment: yeah, Remote Prooedure Call is also running

Comment: Well it sounds like the crux of your problem is you can't get to the SQL Server service properties using Configuration Manager. The fixes I know of are to (a) make sure the browser service is running (b) make sure the port for the instance is available (e.g. shut off Windows firewall) (c) run config manager as admin (d) install the latest SQL Server service pack (this might repair whatever has gone bonkers in your configuration manager).

Comment: installing sql server 2008 sp1,sp2 and sp3 solved the problem

Comment: Service packs are cumulative, so you only needed to install the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest service pack, this should fix the configuration manager issue, which will allow you to properly configure filestream.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 release and it supports only sql server 2008 sp3

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), you need to enable it from SQL Server Configuration Manager.

**EDIT:** You didn't mention that you had already followed the documentation, nor that you can't see any services in the SSCM. According to various Google hits such as [this MS forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/bddbc31f-51c7-4bb8-9274-c15329cc5312/), limited permissions on the `NETWORK SERVICE` account could cause this problem.

Comment: yes, i read it too, but the problem is that in configuration manager when I select sql service nothing appears. see the below image link http://sdrv.ms/R5PxOa

Comment: ok I will check it and let you know. But I have assigned an administrator account to the Sql Server SErvice instead of NetWork Sevice.it's my mistake I have not mentioed about documentation, sorry for that, and thanks for helping me